# Python regular expression remove whitespace around some punctuations

Tags: python, regex

These are the examples:

`s1 = "hello 11 : 23 pm"`  --> `"hello 11:23 pm"`

`s2 = "hello 10, 000 dollars"` --> `"hello 10,000 dollars"`

`s3 = "hello 10. 213 percent"` --> `"hello 10.213 percent"`

`s4 = "hello 11 : 23 pm, 10, 000 dollars, 10. 213 percent"` --> `"hello 11:23 pm, 10,000 dollars, 10.213 percent"`

How to use the regular expression to convert the left strings to the right ones?

Comment: what have you got so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace any punctuation character that is preceded and followed by a digit (with some number of spaces in between) with itself (without the spaces) using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20sub#re.sub):

```py
import re

s1 = "hello 11 : 23 pm" 
s2 = "hello 10, 000 dollars"
s3 = "hello 10. 213 percent" 
s4 = "hello 11 : 23 pm, 10, 000 dollars, 10. 213 percent"

for s in [s1, s2, s3, s4]:
    new = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s*([:,.])\s*(?=\d)', r'\1', s)
    print(new)
```

Output:

```
hello 11:23 pm
hello 10,000 dollars
hello 10.213 percent
hello 11:23 pm, 10,000 dollars, 10.213 percent
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's helpful. However, when I tested the em-dash, it seems not working.

Comment: @Jane you would need to add the em-dash (and any other punctuation character that might occur between digits) to the character set in the middle of the regex (`[:,.]`) to have replacements done around it too. Alternatively, you might find that just replacing `[:,.]` with `[^\w\s]` might be more flexible for you.

Comment: Thanks, @Nick. I just found that I pasted the en-dash instead of em-dash into the square brackets. The two look almost the same in the editor. That's why it doesn't work for em-dash.

Comment: Ah yes, I often do that too! I hope it's working ok now?

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions to solve the problem:

```
import re

input = "hello 11 : 23 pm, 10, 000 dollars, 10. 213 percent"

result = re.sub(r"(\d)\s*([:,.]){1}\s*(\d)", r"\1\2\3", input)

print(result)
```